# Is this how you say "I am irritated with you"?

Tags: grammar

Is this correct or is the form wrong?
私はあなたにイライラしている。

Comment: Can you provide some context? How polite/informal/harsh etc. do you want to sound?

Answer (score 2):

## English

> (1) I am irritated with you.
> (2) 私はあなたにイライラしている。

Grammatically, I think your Japanese translation is correct.
We use expressions similar to (2) when we are irritated with him or her or a third party.
Taking "I'm irritated with him" as an example, there are several ways of expressing it as follows.

> (3) **私｛わたし｝は** 彼にイライラしている。
> (4) 彼にイライラしている。
> (5) 彼に**は**イライラしている。
> (6) 彼にはイライラ**する**。
> (7) 彼には**イラつく**。
> (8) 彼には**ムカつく**。
> (9) **あいつ**にはムカつく。
> (10) **奴｛やつ｝** にはムカつく。
> (11) **彼奴｛あやつ｝** にはムカつく。

I'll add some explanations on expressions from (3) to (11).

- (4) is basically the same as (3), but it is usual in Japanese language to omit subjects already known. Especially when "I" is the subject, we'll omit it without fail, so (4) is used when we want to express it like (3).
- I don't know why, but we generally use (5) rather than (4), though (4) is also natural.
- When expressing a state that we are "irritated" we generally say "イライラする" like (6) rather than "イライラしている" like (5), though I know "イライラする" might corresponds to "become irritated".
- There isn't any problem in the expression with "イライラする", but the expressions such as "イラつく" or "ムカつく" are often used as in (7) and (8).
- We also use "奴｛やつ｝", "あいつ" or "彼奴｛あやつ｝" as in (9), (10) or (11) to insult "him".

There are various expressions for a third party as mentioned above, but Japanese people don't actually use the expression like (2) which is posted by the questioner. At least, I as a Japanese people have never used the expression like (2). That is because we Japanese people don't generally use words that hurt others directly to the person in front of us.

Of course, the reason why you wanted to use the expression like (2) might be because the person had told or done you such things that made you become irritated beforehand.
I said earlier that "Japanese people don't actually use the expression like (2)." If so, everyone would think that the person who irritated you would not take such an action if he was a Japanese people. But he must have done so. Don't you feel any contradiction?

However, there is no contradiction. Even if he does not intend to irritate you, the same behavior of a person may differ depending on the person receiving it, and its way of feeling may be different. Perhaps, he who irritated you probably did not intend to irritate you. Or perhaps he was a kind of a person who was insensitive to the feelings of others, or he might always have been an aggressive person.

By the way, I think you would like to know what Japanese people would do when we are actually irritated like (1).

Thinking about me, I would keep calm with a little grumpy face. Or even if acting normally on the spot, I won't keep company with him thereafter.

## 日本語

> (1) I am irritated with you.
> (2) 私はあなたにイライラしている。

文法的には、あなたの日本語訳は合っていると思います。
彼とか彼女とか第三者にイライラしているときにも、(2)と似た表現を使います。
"I'm irritated with him"を例にすると、次のようにいくつかの表現方法があります。

> (3) **私｛わたし｝は** 彼にイライラしている。
> (4) 彼にイライラしている。
> (5) 彼に**は**イライラしている。
> (6) 彼にはイライラ**する**。
> (7) 彼には**イラつく**。
> (8) 彼には**ムカつく**。
> (9) **あいつ**にはムカつく。
> (10) **奴｛やつ｝** にはムカつく。
> (11) **彼奴｛あやつ｝** にはムカつく。

(3)から(11)までの表現に関して少し説明を加えます。

- (4)は(3)と基本的に同じですが、日本語ではすでに分かっている主語は省略するのが普通です。特に「私」が主語の場合は、間違いなく省略しますので、(3)と表現したいときには(4)を用います。
- 何故か理由は分かりませんが、一般に(4)ではなく(5)のように言います。
- 自分が「イライラしている」状態を表現するときに、一般に(5)よりは(6)のように「イライラする」と言います。
- 「イライラする」でも問題ありませんが、(7)や(8)のように、もっと短い表現である「イラつく」「ムカつく」なども良く使われます。
- 「イライラする」相手が「彼」の場合、(9)、(10)、(11)のように、「彼」を侮辱するために「あいつ」「奴｛やつ｝」「彼奴｛あやつ｝」なども使われます。

上記のように第三者に対しては色々な表現がありますが、最初の質問にあった(2)のような表現は、日本人は実際には使いません。少なくとも、日本人である私は(2)のような表現を使った経験はありません。

それは、日本人は相手の目の前で相手を傷つけるような言葉を一般に使わないからです。
むろん、あなたが(2)のような表現を使いたいということは、その前に、あなたに向かってその人があなたをイライラさせるような言動をとったからでしょう。
先ほど私は、「(2)のような表現は、日本人は実際には使いません。」と言いました。それなら、あなたをイライラさせた人も、その人が日本人ならそのような言動を取らないのではないかという疑問を持つのではないでしょうか。

しかし、それは違います。たとえその人があなたをイライラさせるつもりはなくとも、人の言動にはそれを受ける人によって差があり、感じ方が異なるからです。きっと、あなたをイライラさせた人はあなたにイライラさせる積りはなかったのでしょう。あるいは、その人が他人の気持ちに鈍感であるか、いつも、攻撃的な人なのかもしれません。

ところで、あなたが実際にイライラしてとき、日本人ならどうするか知りたいでしょう。

私なら、少し怖い顔をしてじっと黙っているでしょうね。あるいは、その場では知らん顔をしていても、しばらくはその人と付き合わないかもしれません。